# Using functions to print lowest,highest, and averages of a list

Tags: python, list, function, printing

Using functions, how would I print the lowest, highest, and average of my PAY list that I read from a file?

```
try:
    text_file = open ("Pay.txt", "w")
    text_file.writelines(Pay)
    text_file.close()
except (IOError):
    print 'Error opening/writing Pay.txt'

try:
    text_file= open("Pay.txt","r")
    PAY_= text_file.readlines()
    text_file.close()
    PAY_.sort()
```

I've never set up anything like this, could anyone get me started?I'll thank you ahead of time for your replies. Keep in mind I'm new here, I don't know exactly how you do things...bear with me please.

Answer (score 2):

Presuming that you have one number per line:

```
numbers = [float(line) for line in open('Pay.txt') if line.strip()]
if numbers:
    print 'min', min(numbers)
    print 'max', max(numbers)
    print 'avg', sum(numbers) / len(numbers)
else:
    print 'file is empty or all lines are blank'
```

Comment: @ John Machin Thanks, And this structure would go right under my read file that I have posted?

Comment: @user735324: It's not a "structure", and it *replaces* the read code which you posted (which does nothing useful except closing the file). By the way, if all you are going to do with try/except is replace precise error messages with 'error opening/writing ..' or suchlike, then don't bother.

Comment: code has a structure to it, does it not? I appreciate your help John, wish I could give you some points.

Comment: hmmmmm....It's giving me this error: numbers = IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Pay.txt'  ---not sure why, I wrote the file?

Comment: @user735324: If you are writing it in the same script, check for name typo. Otherwise: Maybe it was deleted after you wrote it. Maybe it's in a directory other than your current working directory.